# Ordering of CSS class for table row, why does the class background colour not override the other defined CSS tr colour?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with class report-table:

```
<table class='report-table'>
<thead>
  <th>Header</th>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
 <tr >
  <td>stuff</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>

 </table>
```

I define my colours (weird colour scheme - but its to do with a django formset that I have rendered in the main body of the table)

css:

```
table.report-table {
  font-family:arial;
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
  margin: 10px 5px 15px 15px;
  font-size: 10pt;
  text-align: center;
    width: 1500px;
}

table.report-table thead {
  font-family: arial;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: black;
    padding: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  font-size: 10.5pt;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;

}

.report-table tbody tr:nth-child(3n+1) td {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

.report-table tbody tr:nth-child(3n+2) td {
    background-color: white;
}

.report-table tbody tr:nth-child(6n+1) td {
    background-color: #d9ffcc;
}

.report-table tbody tr:nth-last-child(3) td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

This works perfectly for my above table, but sometimes when I want to use this table, I want to colour rows orange. I thought that adding this to my css file:

```
.orange-row td {
    background-color: orange; !important;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and then when I do this with my table:

```
<table class='report-table'>
<thead>
  <th>Header</th>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
 <tr class='orange-row'>
  <td>stuff</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>

 </table>
```

It would be an orange row... but this is not the case? Why is this not being pushed to the 'front' and how can I make a class to give rows orange background colour?

Comment: Works as intended. Have you checked in an Inspector if your orange style is actually applied or simply gets overridden?

Comment: You have a typo in your orange row: in `background-color: orange; !important;` you have two semicolons. Remove the first, so its `background-color: orange !important;` and it should work. Or you could make it more specific, by changing `.orange-row td {}` to `table.report-table tr.orange-row td {}`, that should work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the **Cascading** (**S**tyle **S**heets) nature of of CSS that's in play here. And in particular, the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

In short, you can make it work by being more specific.

```
.report-table tbody tr.orange-row td {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Also, you have a typo in the `background-color` property. Replacing the first ; with a : will also work.